# Getting 'IndexError: list index out of range' if I try to add index to the list

Tags: python, list, django-models, indexing, append

I have the following loop.

```
table = []
index = 0

for i in Dog.objects.all():
    table_col1 = (i.pk)
    table_col2 = (i.nickname)
    table_col3 = (i.weight)
    table_col4 = (i.food)
    table_col5 = table[index][1]

    table.append([index, table_col1,table_col2,table_col3,table_col4,
                  put_buttons(['del'], onclick = put_text(table[index][0]))])
```

But I get index error.
how ever when I print the table_col5 **after** the table.appen(), I could get the result right.
how can I add the table index to the table.append function?

Comment: there's quite a lot of code missing here for anyone to be able to help you with this. Can you post the full traceback of the error you're receiving? Can you post the code for `Dog` and for `put_buttons`? We can't see from the code you've posted where the error is coming from.

Comment: Perhaps you want `table` to be a dict rather than a list?

Comment: Your table is an empty list when you say `table[index][1]` on first iteration of a loop. As you can see your table is an empty list from the beginning and you dont modify it and try to get element with index `index`.

Comment: @greg_data it's part of big program. I'm using a not very popular library namely PyWebIO. the problem was that the library had problem so I couldn't iterate through database easily.

Comment: @Samwise, no I wanted exactly list :).

Comment: you are right @Mark. The library had a little problem with iterating. Now I have tried with another way, and it's done.
thanks though.